# Unexpected infinite loading app with Flutter on Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart

During the last update of my application, I noticed an unexpected crash when launching it.

When the app launches on some devices, it gets stuck on the device's native splash screen, which leads me to believe that the app hasn't yet been passed to my widgets and is stuck in the hand.

However, I'm unable to find the source of this problem, as I don't get any error message. So I'm asking you to find out if anyone else has had the same problem?

The only clue I have is that I added this line in my last update, and it's the only change I've made in a very long time:

```dart
ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails flutterErrorDetails) => ErrorPage(detailsException: flutterErrorDetails.exception);
```

I think it could be this line, but I'm not sure what would be wrong.

Here's my complete code. Thanks a lot for your help!

```dart
Future<void> main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  tz.initializeTimeZones();

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);

  // I added this line
  ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails flutterErrorDetails) => ErrorPage(detailsException: flutterErrorDetails.exception);

  runApp(EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('en'), Locale('es'), Locale('fr')],
      path: 'assets/translations',
      fallbackLocale: const Locale('en'),
      child: const MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ConnectionProvider())],
      child: FlutterSizer(builder: (context, orientation, screenType) {
        return MaterialApp(
            localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
            supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
            locale: context.locale,
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: const ResortSelection());
      }),
    );
  }
}
```